# On Tab press, focused element has a border, but when focusing element manually, it does not have border

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have dynamically loaded some li inside a div by ajax call in jQuery. I have coded the function to iterate through these li elements on up and down arrow key.

But I found a weird behavior of focus. When these elements are focused on Tab press, they have border around them, but when these elements are focused by down arrow(function I wrote), it is not having border.

Here is the code of function

```
    if (e.keyCode === 40 && elemID.includes("resultstagsid.")) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //$('#results a').eq(liIndex).removeClass("bg-gray")
                liIndex++
    // $('#results a').eq(liIndex).focus().addClass("bg-gray")
                $('#results a').eq(liIndex).focus()
    
                let scrollTo = $('#results a').eq(liIndex);
                let position = scrollTo.offset().top
                    - container.offset().top
                    + container.scrollTop();
    
                container.animate({
                    scrollTop: position
                });
            }

//Here is the code where li elements are being generated.

const result = $('#results');    
var html = "<ul>"
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            let valu = fuzzysort.highlight(results[i]);
            html += "<li><a href='#' id='resultstagsid." + i + "' name='resultstagsid." + i + "' onclick='selectService(\"" + valu + "\"); ' class='resultsatags'>" + fuzzysort.highlight(results[i]) + "</a></li>"
        }
        html += "</ul>" 
    result.html(html)
```

Note : I am using Admin LTE template. I have also checked for the class if assigned for focused element. But couldn't find. I am trying to style the elements differently and removing border anyway, but I am curious about this behavior even I may be doing some mistake possibly, so please if anyone can explain this.

Here is the screenshot for both behavior

[image: rounded border on focus]

Comment: You can control the tab focused borders with CSS [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) property. Set it to `none` if you want to remove the border.

Comment: I am curious about, why borders are not appearing when focus is set manually

Comment: I'd assume the behavior is related to accessibility, the focused elements are somehow highlighted when moving on a page without actually pointing elements.

Comment: You are saying that, on tab press elements are not actually focused, but just highlighted? But when enter is pressed, it triggers onclick event. So it must be focused to trigger onclick event

Comment: No, they're focused by a user interaction (other than pointer device), when you programmatically gain focus to an element, it's not a user interaction. I didn't test your code, but at least in FF also programmatically focused elements are highlighted too.

Comment: I have changed resolution of screen, it appears for a while and now again not working. I will give it a try to figure it out.

Comment: Screen resolution changes does not affect it, Actually if I press TAB first and then press up or down arrow for manual focus, then Border remains, otherwise in case if TAB is not pressed first, it does not show Borders. @Teemu I checked about accessibility also and came to conclusion that, on TAB press default style is provided by Browser, that is why it shows border. But still don't know why any class or style code is not showing in developer console. _Thanks for your time._

Comment: My first comment tells you how to get rid of the automatic outline ...